# Is it possible to create a GKE node pool in the Standard network service tier

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-networking

With GCP's [network service tiers](https://cloud.google.com/network-tiers/), it's possible to specify that a machine be on the Premium or Standard network service tiers.  The default network service tier for my project in GCP is Premium.  I have some deployments that I'd like to run on a GKE node pool in the Standard service tier, however.  I'm aware of the [annotations for Services](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/service-parameters) to set the service tier, but the deployments in question run via Host networking and are not exposed via services.

Is it possible to specify a node pool using the Standard service tier for networking?  If so, how can you do it?  I'm not seeing anything exposed in the GCP console.  Perhaps via `gcloud` CLI?

ETA:

The deployment in the node pool in question is a bi-directional UDP server.  It doesn't matter if I set up a service for the deployment or not.  The UDP packets always come from the node's ephemeral IP address on the Premium service tier.  So short of a way to make outbound traffic come from the Service IP, I need the node to be on a standard tier IP address.

ETA2:

Tested some things on a throwaway GCP project.  I created a GKE cluster while on the Premium network service tier, then switched to the Standard network service tier and created a second node pool.  The second node pool's assigned IPs are on the Standard service tier as expected.  So back to the original question:  Can this service tier be selected on the creation of the node pool instead of setting the project's whole service tier to Standard?

Comment: Is this a public or private cluster?

Comment: @GariSingh public

Comment: It's a miss use of Kubernetes. The node should be directly accessible without service exposition. Especially for security purpose. Having no configuration for a security hole seems fine.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I understand you perceive this as a security issue.  These are UDP only deployments.  Remote TCP to the cluster is blocked.  The question still remains

Answer (score 0):

It LOOKS like you might be able to do this by (1) setting the things you want to exempt and keep premium as premium in [their service definitions](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/service-parameters), and (2) setting the default to standard. Then when you restart K8S VMs they should inherit standard. Not sure though. Would have to try it.

Posting in case someone else has tried this or knows.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).